# Use Cell Value as Address in Formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

- I have a cell that contains a number - `C2`
- I need to use that number as part of an address in a formula.

Here's the formula it needs to go in: `=COUNT(SEARCH(B$1:B$ 'NUMBER HERE',A1))`

**UPDATE:** I needed it for conditional formatting - to highlight cells that contain specific keywords. The keywords are manually set in column B. The number in C2 determines how many of the keywords will be used. (I found the formula online and seems to work pretty well when the address is manually set)

**UPDATE:** I was able to get it working using the Indirect function as Mikku suggested.

Comment: Use Indirect to do it

Comment: What is your goal, count the occurence of the A1 value in a specified range?

Comment: I need it for conditional formatting - to highlight cells that contain specific keywords. The keywords are manually set in column B. The number in C2 determines how many of the keywords will be used. 

(I found the formula online and seems to work pretty well when the address is manually set)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try** :  `=COUNT(SEARCH(Indirect("B$1:B$" & INDIRECT("C2",TRUE)),A1))`

Indirect gives you the value of a Cell in reference, like in the above formula it will put the value of `C2` in this formula

**Sample Use:**

[image]

Comment: `INDIRECT` is volatile, use `INDEX` instead :). That would be semi-volatile.

Answer (score 1):

Following your logic, you can use:

```
=COUNT(SEARCH(B1:INDEX(B:B,C2),A1))
```

Entered as array through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

[image]

But can you explain why you approuch your problem the way you do? Cause in above example, `=COUNTIF(B1:INDEX(B:B,C2),A1)` would be a non-array entered approach and thus better.

Comment: Forgot to mention - It's needed for conditional formatting.

Comment: @AtanasVasilev, do to what? Update your question with relevant information like this, sample data and expected output. Right now it makes no sense to use that formula in conditional formatting the way you do. Either way, since conditional formatting is always volatile, the use of `INDIRECT` is "allowed".